# How to run romex around window with no studs?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I installed a power outlet between two windows in my garage. I want to run power to the outlet from the other side of one of the windows. The trouble is, there are no studs to run wiring through. The windows are installed such that there are no studs under them, and a large header takes up all the space above them (again, no studs to pass through). What can I do to get the wiring around the window? I'll be putting up drywall after this. The ceiling was finished when I purchased the house. Living space above the garage.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: post a picture of the area that you refer to

Comment: Add a link to a photo.

Comment: you are joking, right? ... where is the power outlet?  ... where are the two windows? .... where is the area under the windows?

Comment: Power outlets are on either side of the window pictured. The problem is there are no studs from the way the window is framed above and below to pass wiring through.

Comment: Do you have access above the ceiling? You could run the wire up into the ceiling, over and back down.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to finish your garage and surface mount either raceway conduit or armored cable. Since this is a garage, the aesthetics shouldn't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

Cut out the drywall at the ceiling and run it through the plates and then the joists and back through the plates again.